# code to find the sum of continuous non-empty cells in a column in excel till the empty cell occurs?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

[image]

In B1 I want to sum all the cells of first column till the empty cell occurs.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))
```

The INDEX/MATCH formula finds the last cell that has a numeric value and sets that as the end of the Range in the SUM() formula.

But ultimately if you want to sum every number in Column A then a simple Sum of the whole column will work:

```
=SUM(A:A)
```

The SUM() Function ignores text and blank cells.

If what is wanted is to sum till the first blank cell and there is data after that then use this instead:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A:A="",0),0)))
```

[image]

Comment: re your edit: Guessing there's gaps in column hence OP wants to set range?

Comment: @findwindow You may be right the OP may want to stop at the first blank.  I will edit.

Comment: Oh. So the index/match finds last LAST cell. Edit: lol if OP really just wanted `sum`... XD Edit2: lol taking away my upvote =P